# ASP connection string to SQL Impersonate

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, impersonation

I'm trying to use Impersonate to connect my ASP.NET to a SQL database.

my string is:

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name="AppEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NModel.csdl|res://*/NModel.ssdl|res://*/NModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
  Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=SSPI;
  Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

the impersonate tag is done this way:

```
<system.web>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="pswd"/><system.web>
```

in this way it does not work, otherwise if I use the SQL authentication it works fine.

any idea of how to solve it?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to specify IIS App pool identity http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx